# Magento - include multiple external libraries to Admin Controller actions

Tags: magento-1.9, import, admin-controller, 3rd-party-library

I am working on import price of products using xls, xlsx, ods and csv files.

For that i need to read these file, i had use seperate external library files to read those files.

It works well in my local machine, when i move it to server my admin controller doesn't work, it displays blank page.

I found that is because i have included external library files in my admin controller.(when i command those lines controller works fine in server)

so then i have used below format to include lib files :

```
require_once(Mage::getBaseDir('lib'). DS . '[folder_name]/easyODS.php');
require_once(Mage::getBaseDir('lib'). DS . '[folder_name]/simplexlsx.class.php');
require_once(Mage::getBaseDir('lib'). DS . '[folder_name]/reader.php');
```

after this change xlsx, ods and csv(i didn't use lib file for csv) working fine but xls doesn't.

kindly give me suggestion to do this stuff.

Comment: anybody faced this issue already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed the issue...simple thing i have done
i have changed the below line in my library file that i used to read .xls file
the line is :

```
function Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader()
{
    $this->_ole =& new OLERead();
    $this->setUTFEncoder('iconv');
}
```

**Changed To**

```
function Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader()
{
    $this->_ole = new OLERead();
    $this->setUTFEncoder('iconv');
}
```

I have just removed the '&'(ampersand) from the line. Problem Solved!!!... Now it is working well.

Comment: can you please describe how to call php library in controller ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all debug the path :

```
require_once(Mage::getBaseDir('lib'). DS . '[folder_name]/easyODS.php');
```

the path which is created able to open file in browser? and then try to add relative path of the file.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i will check with this and let you know

Comment: i have resolved my issue MageComp..above is my answer

Comment: this is not workig in controller.